# Periodic high response time in Tornado web server

Tags: php, python, tornado

I've implemented a Tornado webserver to handle requests from another PHP webserver.  The php requests will cause there to be some simple and consistent data processing before responding. However, when I view the logs I'm periodically seeing spikes in the response time.  For example:

```
INFO:tornado.access:200 POST /v1/conversion/ (192.168.21.247) 3.33ms
INFO:tornado.access:200 POST /v1/conversion/ (192.168.21.222) 3.43ms
INFO:tornado.access:200 POST /v1/conversion/ (192.168.21.247) 3.55ms
INFO:tornado.access:200 POST /v1/conversion/ (192.168.21.222) 3.36ms
INFO:tornado.access:200 POST /v1/conversion/ (192.168.21.247) 58.56ms
INFO:tornado.access:200 POST /v1/conversion/ (192.168.21.222) 3.22ms
INFO:tornado.access:200 POST /v1/conversion/ (192.168.21.222) 3.20ms
INFO:tornado.access:200 POST /v1/conversion/ (192.168.21.247) 3.28ms
INFO:tornado.access:200 POST /v1/conversion/ (192.168.21.222) 3.34ms
```

I have a relatively tight timeout window on the php request (100ms) and every now and then its triggering. So far I've been unable to determine the cause.

Some of the steps I've taken so far:

1. Surrounded my code in the RequestHandler with timing code and configured it to log if my code ever takes longer than 10 ms to run. This has never shown up on the log files. So it doesn't seem my RequestHandler code is causing it.
2. Captured the data that was sent from the PHP server to Tornado on one of the timeouts. I tried re-sending some of these requests in an isolated environment and they responded in the usual time (3-5ms), so it doesn't seem to be caused by the request.
3. This is running in an environment with a lot of traffic (hundreds of requests per second) so I've also increased the number servers to try to better handle the load. This has significantly reduced the number of timeouts, but not eliminated them.

If there is any other information that would help, let me know and I'll try to provide it.  Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this ? I am also facing a similar issue.

Comment: @AljoJose It feels like this was a lifetime ago. Unfortunately I don't remember if we solved this issue, or how we did it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

[`IOLoop.set_blocking_log_threshold`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.set_blocking_log_threshold) is one tool for debugging these kinds of issues. Call `IOLoop.current().set_blocking_log_threshold(0.010)` and it will log a stack trace whenever anything is blocking the IOLoop for more than 10ms.